# Sorting child elements after their parent element

Tags: sql

I'm trying to implement a category table.
A simplified table description is like this

```
id -- name -- parent_id
```

assuming a sample data like

```
id - name - parent_id
1 test1  null
2 test2  null
3 test3  null
4 test4  1
5 test5  4
6 test6  2
7 test7  1
```

I'm struggling to come up with an **sql query** that will return the record set in the following order

```
id - name - parent_id
1 test1  null
4 test4  1
5 test5  4
7 test7  1
2 test2  null
6 test6  2
3 test3  null
```

Basically the child elements are returned after their parent element.

**----------------------- SOLVED BY USING LINQ/recursion in code -------------------------**

Not exactly an sql solution, but ultimately it works.

Comment: I don't think there's enough specification. It seems arbitrary why `test1` was the parent before `test2`, or `test3` for that matter.

Comment: I might be missing the point. But I can't see the relation between the sample data and the order of the expected data. (It is late so if I'm missing the obvious I do apologise)

Comment: test1 should be before test4 is he wants it ordered according to the parent relationship, it follows that test2 being the next id in a ordered list would be the next parent in the results

Comment: Ok got it - 1 first as it is the primary row. 4 follows 1 as its parent is 1, 5 follows 4 as its parent is 4..

Comment: With a single query? no you cant.

Comment: This seems like a schema problem. Why not split it into a table that contains your items, and then a second table that defines their relationship?

Comment: well i was trying to avoid doing multiple queries Ben.

Comment: What server? If you use SQL Server, you can implement it with recursive CTE.

Comment: This is a hierarchical query, and such things are notoriously difficult to code - whether in SQL or any other system.  There are (standard-compliant) dialects of SQL which support a WITH clause and a WITH RECURSIVE clause.  There are other dialects that support CONNECT BY clauses.  Dealing with a 3-level hierarchy as in the question is not too hard; extending it to 4 levels is not too bad, either.  One difficulty is knowing how many levels you need to support, and writing the SQL for each such level - hence the need for the recursive solutions.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you are building something in an application with a loop from this query? and the reason you need this order would be so that you can be sure a parent object exists before you create the child object?

Comment: @robert, See my answer below. I solved it by added an extra column.

Comment: @invertedSpear, yup that's roughly what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do with the query, you don't need to sort it that way. You just need to ensure that the parents are created first. So run your query sorted by parent ID, put the result into an array and loop over that array. On each iteration do a check to make sure parent exists, if it has a parent. If parent doesn't exist, just move that item to the end of the array and go to the next for now, you should only end up with a few cases that get moved so it remains decently efficient.

Answer (score 1):

What I have always done in the past is split the database up into the following (I'm not the best at SQL though so there may be some other solutions for you).

```
categories
 - category_id  |  int(11)  | Primary Key / Auto_Increment
 ..
 ..

sub_categories
 - sub_category_id  |  int(11)  |  Primary Key / Auto_Increment
 - category_id      |  int(11)  |  Foreign Key to categories table
 ..
 ..
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below works by added an extra `order_parent` column that contains either the parent id or the row's id, depending on whether it is the parent. It then just sorts primarily by the `order_parent` id to group them together, then by the `parent_id` to sort the `null`s (actual parents) on top.

Two things:

1. This has one more column that you originally wanted, so just ignore it.
2. In case your database returns the `nulls` of parent_id last, add a `DESC`.

Good question, by the way!

```
SELECT   id,
         name,
         parent_id,
         (
             case
             when parent_id is null then id
             else parent_id
             end
         ) AS order_parent
FROM     myTable
ORDER BY order_parent, parent_id
```

Comment: Have you run this query? It sorts children, but grandchildren (id=5) ends up last

Comment: Ah, grandchildren. Quite. I didn't notice those.

Comment: ya i tried to run it. It looks like it's about to work. but it's not working actually. For simplicity(to avoid the nulls) i copied ids  to the parent id fields for the nodes that don't have a parent.

Comment: I can't think of a way to reconcile this to work for multiple levels of generations. Even if you got the root parent in `order_parent`, you wouldn't have something to sort by to get the grandchildren in the proper order.

Comment: appreciate the effort nonetheless. I'll probably end up doing this via code. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
SELECT id, name, parent_id, (CASE WHEN COALESCE(parentid,0)=0 THEN id ELSE (parentid + '.' + id)) as orderid
FROM table
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN COALESCE(parentid,0)=0 THEN id ELSE (parentid + '.' + id))
```

This should create a new column called orderid that has the parentid dot the id (1.4, 4.5, etc.)  For the columns where the parent id is null, it would put just the id.  This way you would get the order as 1, 1.4, 4, 4.5, etc.

Please check the code since I wrote this on the fly without testing.  It should be close.